# Knex JS escape ilike special characters with url string bindings

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to use `ilike` in a knex js query (node/postgres) to find domains with matching hosts and path names but different prefixes (`www.site.com` and `m.site.com` would both come up in this query). I am able to type out the full string and get a response but not when I pass a variable/binding.

Works:

```
knex("table")
.select()
.whereRaw("column_name ilike '%domain.com/path-string-here/%'")
```

Does not work:

```
const url = 'domain.com/path-string-here/';

knex("table")
.select()
.whereRaw(`column_name ilike '%${url}%'`)
```

The SQL comes out the same on my console but the second query returns an empty array. I know there I need to escape the special characters in some way since I'm using template literals but nothing I'm finding is matching up with my exact scenario.

I have also tried doing the whole query in `knex.raw` and playing around with `whereIn` and `whereILike` but I get the same results (or worse errors).

EDIT: I also tried variations of `knex.where('column_name', 'ilike', url)` with the same results -- empty return.

Comment: I think you may have missed the parameter binding part in my answer, your examples do not cover passing a var. You first bind param in `raw` and then pass that to `where`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're passing parameters directly into SQL. **Do not do that.** [Raw is meant to be used when you need more control and non-standard features](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html) like `ilike` and you're correct on using it here. But there's a better way, since knex actually supports `ilike`.

However `column_name ilike '%${url}%'` is asking for a trouble ([sqli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), you should do it like this, utilising parameter binding:

```
    const concatDomain = db.raw(`concat('%', ?::text, '%')`, domain)

    return db('table')
        .select()
        .where('name', 'ilike', concatDomain)
```